# Are moving ships harder to hit by macro weapons?

Tags: battlefleet-gothic-armada-2

While it seems like a silly question (it seems logical that moving target is HARDER to hit than a static one), I am wondering if this is true in the game mechanic?

In the Battlefleet:Gothic Armada 2 we have weapons that always hit (lances, zzap, missiles), dummy weapons that you can evade (torpedoes, various bombs) and then you have the regular "macro cannons" that have "x% chance to hit".

Is this chance calculated only based on the distance (as in weapon description - i.e. 80% hit below 4500 units) and it is decided when the attacker shoots, or is the opponent position and movement taken into consideration (so the defender can dodge the bullets).

I am wondering this, since if the former is true, then the "sitting duck" (stay in place and just keep aiming) strategy for vessels with strong prow armour and front facing guns (like i.e. Empire's Dauntless light cruiser) more viable than the usual attempt to "dance" around the opponent? Or will you get hit more often this way?